# I need to disprove one of these statements.

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please provide a counterexample to the statement:

If $f(x) = g(x)$ for all real numbers other than $x=0$, and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$, then $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x) = L$

If I'm being honest, there might not be a counterexample and this statement may be true. I have just not been able to disprove:
if $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L$, then $f(c) = L$

For context, my calc class was told that there is only one true statement out of the six that we were assigned, and these are the two I have narrowed it down to.

Comment: When you work at disproving something and get stuck maybe the statement is true and it's time to try to prove it.

Comment: Write down the definition of the limit in the context of $f$ and ask if it must be true with $f$ replaced by $f$.

Comment: I'm sorry for writing down the answers. I realized that it doesn't help you to think. So, I've deleted my previous comment.

Comment: If I were to cover up the part of the graph of $f$ over $x=0$ with my hand, could you tell me whether you were seeing the graph of $f$ or the graph of $g$? Note that the value of these limits has nothing to do with the value of the functions at that point.

Comment: The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = L$ means that for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such whenever $0<|x|<\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.  Now for the same $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, we have $$|g(x)-L|=|g(x)-f(x)+f(x)-L|\le |g(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-L|=0+|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: Regarding $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ implying or not implying that $f(c)=L$... that is something called "*continuity*".  Consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\neq 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$.  This is a perfectly valid function to consider.  Is the limit as it approaches $0$ equal to the value it has at $0$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't even consider piecewise functions when trying this... Thanks a bunch

Comment: By definition the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ depends on the values of $f$ at $0<|x|<\delta$  for any fixed $\delta>0.$ Hence $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$